# Levi Civita notation and understanding

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am learning (again) the Levi Civita notation. The explanation in Class was brief and we didn't explain rules on how to operate with the incidences. I am having troubles understanding how the 2nd notation below is similar to the first:

$\nabla \times(\nabla u)=0$. I understand this.

Then in the Levi civita notation we have:

$c_i=\epsilon_{ijk}u_{,k,j}=\epsilon_{ijk}u_{,j,k}=-\epsilon_{ikj}u_{,j,k}=-\epsilon_{ijk}u_{,k,j}=0$.

I know that the"," with an index behind is used to represent a partial derivation w.r.t a component.

I don't understand the following things:

1. $u_{,k,j}$ here one index represent the derivation that comes from the scalar product inside the brackets and the other one comes for the cross product. My question is: Which is which, and is it ok not to differ which comes from cross product and which comes from scalar product?
2. Then we change the places between the indices j and k on $u_{,k,j}$ to $u_{,j,k}$. How can I know that i am able to do this kind of index change WITHOUT having to add a minus before?
3. Can you write the 2nd equation like this:$c_i=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(\partial u(x_m))_k$. It's probably wrong.But my goal was to write it similarly to how we write a simple cross product.

Maybe a book or a pdf, with detailed explanation on how the Levi Civita notation works and which are the rules would also help.

The thing that I want to know is that, if I read something which is written in levi civita notation, should I always be able to understand it what it represents in the normal notation? Personally I would like to be able to do that, if it is possible. Let me elaborate what I am trying to ask:

If we have the cross product between two vectors, but this is not told and I need to figure this out. This is the following notation that I would look at:

$c_i=\epsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k$.

I can understand that this notation represents:

$\vec c=\vec a\times \vec b$

But this is a very simple case of the use of the Levi Civita notation. There are plenty that are way more complicated then this. If I fundamentally understand this kind of notation, should I be able to understand what kind of geometrical process is going on?

Comment: I'd write the second equation as $\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_j\partial_k u$. Technically speaking, the order of the derivatives does matter. Unless the resulting function is continuous, in which case it's independent of the order of the derivatives. But that's a standard assumption in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It doesn't practically matter which of $j,k$ belongs to the gradient ($\nabla u$) and which belongs to the curl ($\nabla\times$) since partial derivatives commute: $u_{,k,j}=u_{,j,k}.$
2. Partial derivatives commute. There is no minus sign. Don't confuse interchanging indices of $u_{,j,k}$ with interchanging indices on $\epsilon_{ijk}.$
3. You have a free index $m$ on the right hand side, but it's not on the left hand side. This is not allowed. Perhaps you want to do the following:
   $$
   [\nabla\times(\nabla u)]_i
   = \epsilon_{ijk} [\nabla]_j [\nabla u]_k
   = \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j (\partial_k u)
   = \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j u_{,k}
   = \epsilon_{ijk} u_{,k,j},
   $$
   where $[\bullet]_i$ stands for the $i$:th component of $\bullet$.

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks for the clarification. Can you recommend me any book or maybe a pdf that thoroughly explains the levi civita notation and it's rules ?

Comment: [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol)

Comment: In 3 dimensions: $\epsilon_{123}=1,$ and $\epsilon_{ijk}$ changes sign when two indices change switch places. This implies that for example $\epsilon_{321}=-\epsilon_{312}=\epsilon_{132}=-\epsilon_{123}=-1.$