# Levi Civita identity

Tags: linear-algebra

We are given the following  following identity in levi civita notation without derivation and I wanted to try how far I can go by trying to derivate it myself. And I couldn't advance at all because I do not know the rules:

$\nabla\times(\nabla\times\vec A)$

I tried in the following way:

$\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(\epsilon_{lmn}\partial_mA_n)_k$

But I don't know the rules now. Can I remove the $\epsilon_{lmn}$ out without having an indecs "k" ?

Can I name the 2nd $\epsilon$ as $\epsilon_{klm}$ and not as I did? How can I know that I can do that? And is it ok if I don't and just write it as i initially wrote it, would I be able to reach the correct result even though my index notation is different then in my script ?

In the scrip when we consider the case of double cross product the two $\epsilon$'s have the same indexes like mine. While when we are given the above equation in the notation you can see that "k" is in both $\epsilon$'s

I should get the following : $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm}A{m,i,j}$

Comment: You can not remove $\epsilon_{lmn}$ but you can move it out of the derivative. But what do you mean with index $k$ on $(\epsilon_{lmn}\partial_m A_n)_k$?

Comment: I simply am trying to reach the results by shifting and moving the indices. In our definition of the double cross product we had the following notation $\epsilon_{ijk}$ and $\epsilon_{lmn}$. As you can see there is not a single index that can be found in both $\epsilon$'s. While in the partial solution of the above identity the scrip starts the proof with $\epsilon_{ijk}$ and $\epsilon_{klm}$. Here "k" is in both $\epsilon$'s. So my question is how do I know that I am allowed to have the same letter in both and what if I don't choose this case, but the initial one. Can I get the right result?

Comment: Do you understand what the indices denote?

Comment: Why don't you try to follow the way I used in [my answer to your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4226952/168433)?

Comment: I did follow that way. And now I have that "k" outside the bracket and I don;t know what to do with it.In the previous case there was no index on the partial sign, but now there already is one, and another one is outside the brackets. Yes I know what the indices mean (I assume I do)

Comment: Then show every step like I did.